# How to order by higher id sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have rows in MYSQL.

They are basically articles and rumours based on user input. In my query, i would like the table created to have the later results ranked higher. How would that Order By Query work?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rumours";
$query.= "ORDER BY"
$query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $band = $row['band'];
     $title = $row['Title'];
     $description = $row['description'];
     echo "<table border='1'>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td> $title  </td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td class = 'td1'> $description </td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC` Or if there is some sort of creation date, `ORDER BY creation_date_col DESC`.

Comment: If you give us all of the columns in `rumors` we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Few things regarding your snippet.

1. Use a column list and avoid selecting `*`
2. `mysql_` functions are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com). You should use either `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions.
3. You can save yourself time by calling your columns directly, rather than reassigning them variables.
4. When you are asking for the *older* records to display first, what is the criteria for this? Does a higher `id` mean the record is newer? I've assumed this in my answer.

Here's an improved version of your code using `mysqli_`:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$q = "SELECT id, band, Title, description FROM rumours ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $q);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
     echo "<table border='1'>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[id] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td class = 'td1'>" . $row[description] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</table>";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
```